# Adobe media server: apply actionscript code

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-media-server

I'm configuring Adobe Media Server for saving live stream video to .f4v format.
I have main.asc file to do that but I don't know how to apply this file to server.

I have researched on google, but almost results were
https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/ssaslr/topics/server-side-actionscript-language-reference.html

Comment: update your question to include your code from `main.asc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solve. I just put main.asc in "streams" folder.
Then **restart** server. It worked.